# Flutter Location purpose

Tags: flutter, geolocation, location, helper

I need your help...
Can I send my location to many people with one click using flutter?

I don't try anything. I am just asking a question and I want to know this question answer. Thank you

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186049/is-it-possible-to-share-your-location-through-flutter-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to share your location through flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186049/is-it-possible-to-share-your-location-through-flutter-app)